# Always keep cell on the top of uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have an application that is viewbased and I am adding a ***uitableview*** as a subview to the main view. The ***uitableview*** is full with class Category cells. Everything works fine, but I want to have “Quick notes” Category always on the top of the ***uitableview***. This means when I reloadData() in the Array, “Quick Notes” is always with index 0 and it goes on the bottom of the ***uitableview***. And when I create new ***cell*** I need it to go under the “Quick Notes” section.
Please help me, what code I need to achieve that functionality and where I need to put it. Thanks!

Edit:
Thats where I am adding "Quick Notes" to the Realm database.

```
private let categories = try! Realm()

private init() {
    if categories.objects(Category.self).isEmpty {
        createCategoryWith(title: "Quick Notes", color: "#FF0000", icon: "quickNotes")
    }
}
```

Update the array in the ViewController:

```
func didCreateCategory(category: Category) {
    RealmHandler.shared.createCategoryWith(title: category.title, color: category.color, icon: category.icon)
    self.categories = RealmHandler.shared.getAllCategories()
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

DataSourceDelegate:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "categoryCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = categories[categories.count - (1+indexPath.row)].getTitle()
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor(hex: categories[categories.count-(1+indexPath.row)].getColor())
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code on how you are adding `Quick notes` to your array and then reloading your table ? I think we can figure out a solution from there.

Comment: Why don't you use a header on your table?

Comment: @MahyarZhiani how can I make the index 0 of the array sectionheader?

Comment: use `viewForHeaderInSection` delegate method of tableView.
here you can define your header cell.
this method: `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `viewForHeaderInSection` delegate method of tableView.

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int)
```

here you can define your header cell.
then implement your logic that what do you want to show on this cell.
this headerCell will be always on top of your tableView.